# Partially deserializing a JSON string with multiple roots

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am coding a C# version 4 application that consumes REST web services.  Those web services are written with ASP.NET MVC RESTful  web service approach.  Half of those web service methods return JSON strings with **multiple roots** (please see the sample JSON data below).  However, for a specific JSON response (please see one below), I would like partially deserialize a **multiple-root** JSON response string into an Device object (e.g. belonging to Device class) which I am interested in instead of all of the data response.

I know how to use C# .NET library or JSON.net codes to deserialize a JSON string that has only one root.  But I am not sure how to do with multiple-root JSON data.  Please advice. Thank you.

For instance, with the following JSON response, I want to retrieve data for “device” object (instantiated from Device class), and **ignore** “version_info” and “SKU_info” data.

The following JSON response has 3 roots: "version_info", "SKU_info", and "device":

```
{
     “version_info” : { “version” : “1.0”, “owner_id” : 237},
     “SKU_info” : {“id” : 1928399, “active”: true},
     “device” : {
           “id”: 7732, “name” : “desktop computer ”, “parent_device_id”: 2982,
           “sub_devices”: 
           [   
                    {“id”: 7733, “name”: “fan”, “quantity” : 1 }, 
                    {“id”: 7734, “name”: “memory chip”, “quantity” : 4 },
                    {“id”: 7735, “name”: “CPU”, “quantity” : 1 },
                    {“id”: 7736, “name”: “hard disk”, “quantity” : 2 },
           ],
           “user_id” : 864
      }
}
```

And my csutom “Device” and "SubDevice" classes:

```
public class Device
{
    public long Id;
    public string Name;
    public long ParentDeviceId;
    public List<SubDevice> Subdevices;
    public int UserId;
}


public class SubDevice
{
    public long Id;
    public string Name;
    public int Quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string does have a root.  It is just un-named.

```
{  
     “version_info” : { “version” : “1.0”, “owner_id” : 237},
     “SKU_info” : {“id” : 1928399, “active”: true},
     “device” : {
           “id”: 7732, “name” : “desktop computer ”, “parent_device_id”: 2982,
           “sub_devices”: 
           [   
                    {“id”: 7733, “name”: “fan”, “quantity” : 1 }, 
                    {“id”: 7734, “name”: “memory chip”, “quantity” : 4 },
                    {“id”: 7735, “name”: “CPU”, “quantity” : 1 },
                    {“id”: 7736, “name”: “hard disk”, “quantity” : 2 },
           ],
           “user_id” : 864
      }
}
```

The `{` at the very beginning and end `}` that wrap the JSON defines the root object.  So, if you create an object (named anything you would like) then you can deserialize into your new object.

For example:

```
public class Wrapper
{
     Version version_info { get; set; }
     SKU SKU_info { get; set; }
     Device device { get; set; }
}
```

In order to ignore you could just let it deserialize into a dynamic object that you don't intend to use.  This might work:

```
public class Wrapper
{
     dynamic version_info { get; set; }
     dynamic SKU_info { get; set; }
     Device device { get; set; }
}

Wrapper root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(feed);
```

Comment: Thanks, dtryon. It seems, dynamic type does the trick. I'll try your hints.